# How to pass dynamic variable in object while parsing json

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to parse a object ,using Foreach ,
it works good when i use :

```
this.parsedUserInfo.info.tw // or discord any.. from the below list.
```

I want to make the code small using foreach loop but the dyanmic value 'social' is not getting added to the parse statement in if else loop.
My code below:

```
 this.parsedUserInfo = UserInfo.fromJson(jsonDecode(value.data)),
              ['tw', 'discord', 'telegram', 'fb', 'tumblr'].forEach((social) {
               
                if (('this.parsedUserInfo.info.' + social != '')) { //if loop is not working properly.
                  this
                      .parsedPlatforms
                      .data[this
                          .parsedPlatforms
                          .data
                          .indexWhere((row) => row.socid == social)]
                      .connected = true;
                }
```

Comment: Dart isn't JavaScript.  You cannot magically convert strings into code.  JavaScript can do it because JavaScript is interpreted, and an interpreter already converts strings into code, so implementing an `eval()` function is trivial.  Dart is compiled; for Dart to be able to have an `eval()` function, your compiled binary would need to include the entire Dart compiler and SDK.

Comment: Hello @jamesdlin
Thanks for valuable information, how should i proceed on the above then?
Make a spaghetti if else loop for each ? since i have more in the list.